# Question asking for a link

Tags: support, questions

Recently just came across [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/17391/27189) which attracted [this answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/30621/27189) which is a link only answer (it loses any value of the link becomes obsolete).

Thing is, this answers what OP asks, so the answer itself is ok (meaning that it can't be flagged as "Not an Answer" which is the procedure used for such answers in Stack Overflow). This makes me think that there must be something wrong with the question for such answer to be valid.

How to proceed in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was based on a misunderstanding of how Scrum is "versioned." There's no "Scrum 2.0" or "Scrum 3.0", so the question itself was flawed. The accepted answer addresses this in detail, and I myself [added a comment](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17391/is-scrum-updated-to-2-0-or-3-0/30621#comment37452_17391) pointing out that this was a problematic way to phrase the underlying question.

In [this answer](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/877/4271) here on meta, Bart correctly points out that the answer was flag-worthy for a number of different reasons. A number of other people agreed, and flagged appropriately.

In response to the flags, the problematic "answer" has since been moved to a comment on the original question. While the post was relevant to the question asked, it was certainly not an acceptable answer as we have defined them within the PMSE community. From my personal point of view, the community addressed the issue appropriately through flags, and the necessary actions were taken.

Answer (score 3):

As I read the question, it does not (only) ask for the location of the latest Scrum guide, but it also askes if and how the Scrum process is versioned.

Based on that, I *did* come to the conclusion that the answer you linked to is flag-worthy as "Not an Answer".

Besides that, I believe flagging the answer as "Very Low Quality" would also be a viable option.